# How to statistically analyze this data?

Tags: statistical-significance, predictive-models

For my school I'm doing a science project, where one of the requirements is a "statistical analysis of gathered data".

I'm good with most math, but I know nothing about statistics. Now most of my peer's data is simple enough, but mine looks like this: (red is independent variable, blue is dependent variable)

[image]

What isn't shown is a blue line under that red line that mirrors it exactly. That blue line is *one data set*, with every x value having exactly one y value. Through experimentation, I've also found those smaller curves are simply the red values divided by some integer.

I'm not sure what "statistical analysis" means in this context, nor what to do with my data. I think what they want is a model that allows me to predict future values, in which case - how can I do this with this data?

Comment: I think people are going to need more detail to be able to point you in the right direction. What are these variables? Why are the predictor variables equal to the outcome divided by a small integer?

Comment: @mdewey The independent and dependent variables are both numbers associated with elliptic curves. I'm not quite sure why the predictor is equal to the outcome divided by an integer.

Comment: If it's related by a constant coefficient then a simple linear regression $Y~Xβ$ will give you a "perfect" fit, i.e., the predictor and response will be mapped with zero loss. Not sure what you would learn from that, though. Maybe you could speak to your instructor and get a better sense of what he/she is looking for.

Comment: The request "statistical analysis of gathered data" is not a goal, but a means *(it can be only a goal in the context of a teacher requiring you to learn the application of statistics, but still it won't be isolated from some other goal that must be assumed by the analysis)*. **What is your goal with this science project?**

Comment: Also, try to plot your "every x value having exactly one y value" on a plot of x versus y. That is a much easier view. Your current x-axis can always be plotted as a secondary axis,

Comment: If you plot your independent variable on the x-axis and your dependent variable on the y-axis, I think you will get a cone-shaped relationship. Then if you log-transform both variables, and plot them the same way, I think you will see a straight line relationship between your two variables. That might help you think about statistical approaches that could be meaningful.